# Setting a Default Parameter in Pentaho

Tags: reporting, pentaho

This seems like a very trivial question, but I'm trying to add default parameters to a report in Pentaho (I'm using PRD 3.9.1 for Mac). The report has three parameters: Value, Type, and Launch.

When I click on the box for "Default Value" in the parameter settings it gives me a "..." button. When I click on the "..." it gives me a popout window, but I can't figure out how to add a string in the popout window:

[popout window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ21r.jpg)

When I tried adding a formula in the formula field instead, it never actually selected a parameter when I ran the report:

[formula field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0UdC.jpg)

Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thank you very much

Monica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple thing, just add value in popout window u got, add value there. 
It will keep that value as default if u don't pass value for that parameter, You don't have to do anything in formula field

Comment: Actually, it seems that the problem was that I had the parameter type set as "object" rather than "string." When I set it to string it let me type into the box when it would not before.